# jqgrid edit form generates empty space when reopened

Tags: jqgrid

I have a very odd behavior with edit form in jqgrid.  When the form pops up for the first time, it looks like it's supposed to.  If I close it, and edit another record, the edit form pops up with lots of empty space between the last field and the submit' and 'cancel' "buttons".  I tried using 'height' value along the 'navGrid' settings, but that doesn't help.  In fact, if the 'height' value is not large enough, the 'submit' and 'cancel' buttons are not even visible, because they are too low.

The issue is that the form itself (not the modal) gets modified after it is reopened.  I looked at the source of the form, and it seems like when it is first opened, the height is set to auto, but when it is reopened, it has a specified height, in my case 540px.

Very strange.  Anyone have an idea?