# jqGrid edit form fields column width is increased each time the form opens

Tags: jqgrid

If I refresh the page, the edit form looks okay the first time it  opens. After that each time it reopens without refresh, the width of the fields column is increased and the height of the form is decreased hiding thus, elements from the bottom (such as buttons).
I tried even setting the width of the form on onDbClickRow but this didn't work either.
Possibly this is related to [jqgrid edit form generates empty space when reopened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22999699/jqgrid-edit-form-generates-empty-space-when-reopened)

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found is to manually set the width and height on form's style on ondblClickRow event, e.g.

```
    $('#editmodelementsList').css("width", "600px");
    $('#editmodelementsList').css("height", "235px");
```